# Common utility classes for Android testing projects

Tags: android, android-library, android-testing

I keep tests for my Android projects in four separate projects: unit and functional tests separately, and tests that require native Android environment (Activity/Service tests, functional Robotium tests) separated from tests that I suppose can safely be run in artificial environment (Robolectric + some acceptance tests for non-strictly-Android libraries). However, I need to share some utility classes between some of the projects (mostly I mean the Android Test Kit ones, but it would be nice if I could have them under Robolectric too).

How should I go about this problem? Should I create an Android library or a simple JAR with the stub android.jar as a dependency? I've tried both solutions but got strange errors like `NoClassDefFoundError` for classes from the support library or `IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation` for classes from the tested project.

Answer (score 0):

This approach, "a simple JAR with the stub android.jar as a dependency", seems simpler. In your test project, besides including this JAR as a dependency, you need to check the box for this JAR in the "Order and Export" tab of "Java Build Path" in the project property if you are using Eclipse.